# UDP socket buffer space exception c#

Tags: c#, sockets, buffer, udpclient

I have a C# program which fully depends on UDP socket, the receive function is this:

```
private void UdpListener()
{
    State state = new State();
    _socket.BeginReceiveFrom(state.Buffer, 0, BufferLength, SocketFlags.None, ref epFrom, recv = (ar) => 
    {
        State so = (State) ar.AsyncState;
        int bytes = _socket.BeginReceiveFrom(so.Buffer, 0, BufferLength, SocketFlags.None, ref epFrom, recv, so);
        var eventArgs = new NetworkReceivedBytesEventArgs(so.Buffer);
        UdpRx?.Invoke(null, eventArgs);
    }, state);
}
```

This code is working perfectly for about half an hour and receives data correctly, then suddenly the exception in the picture below appears from nowhere.

Please help me fix this problem, or give me a better UDP receive code.

[image: this picture is the exception]

Comment: This is not a [mcve]. How large is the message that is being received? How large is the `state.Buffer`? But more importantly, why is your async callback calling `BeginReceiveFrom()` again? It needs to call `EndReceiveFrom()` instead. [Read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.beginreceivefrom?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: Hi @RemyLebeau .. "How large is the message that is being received" it is 256 bytes, "How large is the state.Buffer" it's **1024 bytes**, "why is your async callback calling `BeginReceiveFrom()` again? It needs to call `EndReceiveFrom()` instead." in this event "`UdpRx?.Invoke(null, eventArgs);`" `EndReceiveFrom()` is called. Thanks for your help ^_^

Comment: but you are calling `BeginReceiveFrom()` **twice** during a *single* read operation. The 2nd call simply does not belong and needs to be removed. Call `BeginReceiveFrom()` **once**, and when its callback is fired then call `EndReceiveFrom()` to finish the read that is already in progress. THEN can `BeginReceiveFrom()` when you are ready to begin a *new* read operation.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i will try it .. Thank you